# clion build failed,cmake command build sucess while failed when parallel build

Tags: cmake, clion

I recently use clion to build my project, I can use cmake to build all of my project, but use clion build all failed. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

I use clion version is 2017.2,use clion bundled cmake 3.8.2 and gdb 3.5.1.
my project structure：

project
├── project1
│   ├── src
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── project2
│   ├── src
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── project3
│   ├── src
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└──CMakeLists.txt

project's CMakeLists.txt is:

```
add_subdirectory(./project1)  
add_subdirectory(./project2)  
add_subdirectory(./project3)
```

project1's CMakeLists.txt use to build static lib1.a:

```
aux_source_directory(./src ${LIB1_SRC})  
include_directories(./src ${LIB1_INC})  
add_library(lib1 STATIC ${LIB1_SRC})
```

project2's CMakeLists.txt use to build static lib2.a:

```
aux_source_directory(./src ${LIB2_SRC})  
include_directories(./src ${LIB2_INC})  
add_library(lib2 STATIC ${LIB2_SRC})
```

project3's CMakeLists.txt need to link lib1.a and lib2.a to build a share lib3.so:

```
aux_source_directory(./src ${LIB3_SRC})  
include_directories(./src ${LIB3_INC})  
add_library(lib3 SHARED ${LIB3_SRC})   
target_link_libraries(lib3 ${LIB1_PATH}/lib1.a  ${LIB2_PATH}/lib2.a)  
set_property(TARGET lib3 PROPERTY LINK_DEPENDS ${LIB1_PATH}/lib1.a  ${LIB2_PATH}/lib2.a)
```

**when I use clion run/debug configuration to choose lib3 and buld, it will build failed, says lib1, or sometimes lib2 needed by lib3.so. I can use clion to build lib1 and lib2 sucess when choose lib1 and lib2 in run/debug configuration**

**I have an another try, I use cmake ./ , then make -j 16, it has the same problem. if I use make -j 1 ,it build sucess.**
Why it can't parallel build? Does clion default use parallel build?

Best Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Your CMakeLists.txt are not complete but i guess changing the target_link_libraries for lib3 like this should fix your issue

```
target_link_libraries(lib3 lib1 lib2)
```

Regarding your CLion question, File->Settings->Build,Execute,Deployment->cmake->Build options

here you can configure if you want to use parallel build

Comment: what is the difference between target_link_libraries(lib3 lib1 lib2) and target_link_libraries(lib3 ${LIB1_PATH}/lib1.a  ${LIB2_PATH}/lib2.a), mine is just add full lib path and an .a; as I can use cmake build sucess, when don't build in parallel. I have a try as you said, it's the same with before

Comment: when remove .a, cmake ./ && make can't sucess, so .a  can't remove

Comment: you are adding a dependency on a file, while it should be a dependency on a target. What is the error message?